# Can anyone please tell me how to calculate discrete wavelet transform of a derivatve?

Tags: derivatives, transformation, wavelets

if $W^{m}[]$ is the wavelet transform of any function at decomposition level m, then how can I calculate

$W^{m}[\frac{d}{dx} f(x)]$,

if fact I want to know if

$W^{m}[\frac{d}{dx} f(x)] = \frac{d}{dx}(W^{m}[f(x)])$
and if this does not hold, why?

Comment: hi and welcome to the site. you can edit and type the typesetting code inside $$ and it will become readable.